# Are there any established mechanics for firing into close combat and missing very badly?

Tags: savage-worlds, fumbles

While working my way through the combat rules, the need to shoot into close combat came up.

The attacker, a Human with a Smith and Wesson .357 (2d6+1) wanted to shoot a frogman who has just Stunned another Human in close combat.

Of course her Shooting and Wild dice landed on snake eyes. In my view, an epic fail.

So I started looking for what to do when you miss so bad something catastrophic should happen. I figured it would be something like the hit would randomly go to a character in base contact and she would have to roll to wound her friend.

But I'm having trouble finding something like that in the rule book. I'll probably play it for the catastrophe in my game, because playing to fail is more fun) but I wondered if there was an established way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Innocent Bystanders rule on page 64 applies here.

> Each miss that comes up a 1 on the Shooting die indicates a random adjacent character was hit. If the attacker was firing on full-auto or with a shotgun, a roll of 1 or 2 hits the bystander. Roll damage normally.

Note that this triggers whenever a Shooting die comes up 1, not just on snake eyes. The new target is picked randomly and gets hit regardless of their defenses. This means it can actually be easier to hit particularly dodgy opponents by shooting at targets next to them; this quirk is even acknowledged in the rules themselves.

Comment: Worth noting that this also makes Rapid Attacks and multiple-projectile *bolt* attacks much more dangerous since that means more chances for a 1 to come up on the dice.